# Algorithm for Separating Consonant and Vowel Waveforms from Speech Signal

Tags: phonetics, speech-recognition, speech-synthesis

Is anyone aware of a software package or general algorithm that allows the separation of consonant and vowel waveforms from a continuous speech signal?

I've tried to implement the technique "Harmonic/Percussive Separation using Median Filtering" by Fiztgerald but I can't seem isolate just the consonant or vowel.  I think I might have to specify the median filter length in the time (harmonic) and frequency (percussive) direction to match up with the properties of the vowel/consonant I want to separate but not sure how to do this.

I could spend ages trying to fine tune this algorithm so I was hoping someone might have a solution already in hand since I am hard pressed for time on this research project (synthesizing speech waveforms for psychophysics experiments).

*Aside:  The HPS technique mentioned above works by filtering a signal in the frequency or time domain to find the dominant bands that contribute to either a harmonic (time) or percussive (freq) component of the signal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about finding software and so it invites for opinionated answers.

Comment: ? But the question seems pretty straightforwardly "has anybody created any such software", which isn't a matter of opinion.

Comment: My question is simply, despite your opinion of what technique/software is best, is there any algorithm out there that allows accurate separation of consonants and vowels from a speech waveform?  The simplest case would be decomposing a 'bIH' syllable into it's respective phonemes.  The technique above is the only thing I found close enough to fit my purposes but it leaves a lot to be desired..

Comment: Is this for English?

Comment: Why don't you consider the inverse and see how speech synthesizers work or more pertinently Vocoders.

Comment: Yes this is for english -- I've been playing a lot with speech synthesizers, specifically macintalk.  I've created a database of phonemes and consonants along with their spectrums and other signal properties.  However it is not yet clearly apparent to me how to accurately separate these signals into their phonemic features. Thanks for the hint ARi, I didn't know a vocoder was the term for a speech synthesizer.  I've spent some time looking under the hood of MacinTalk but to no avail, I'll read up on vocoders on general and will let you guys know what I find =)

Comment: How would such a software distinguish between non-percussive consonants ('M', or 'W' for example, or worse '-ng') and vowels? Teasing apart the vowels from the consonants in English seems like an almost impossible task except as letters spoken in isolation. Can you tell us what the ultimate purpose of the project is so we might suggest alternative approaches?

Comment: I am creating synthesized streams of CV syllables for word segmentation experiments (following Saffran, Newport & Aslin 1996).  I would like to control for the duration of each syllable by using the WSOLA time modification algorithm.  To get good time compression without artifacts, I have to specify anchor points within the syllable waveform at the beginning of the signal, consonant onset/end and vowel onset/end.  I have already done this manually but I was wondering if there was a way to separate the consonant and syllable waveform to automate this time consuming task.

Comment: Here is the paper on the MATLAB toolbox I am using:  [TSM MATLAB TOOLBOX](http://www.dafx14.fau.de/papers/dafx14_jonathan_driedger_tsm_toolbox_matlab_imple.pdf)

Comment: PS -- I am using the following consonants: [p, b, t, k, l, r, g, d]  and the following vowels:  [IH, UW, AE, OW, UW]

Comment: Another followup--do you know ahead-of-time the content of the speech signal as a whole (i.e., is the main problem that needs solving just figuring out where the consonants and vowels align)? Or do you need to be able to pick out the different segments "from scratch"?

Comment: My primary goal is to to align the consonants and vowels in time across syllables, however as I read more about psychoacoustics I think it would be very interesting to figure out how the different segments could be picked out

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the short answer for this is:

*"there's no algorithm that will always agree with your judgements about what is/isn't a vowel/consonant (cf.  glides) and will always agree with your judgements about where said phones start/end in the signal"*

BUT, a bit of quick Googling turned up the following, which may be useful if you're familiar with Praat:

http://robfelty.com/academic-files/praat/DetectVowels.praat

Comment: thanks Fred! this looks like what I'm looking for but I'm going to have to read up on scripting in praat first to figure out if it suits my needs

Answer (score 2):

If you know beforehand the content of the speech signal but you just don't know which parts of the waveform correspond to which parts of the utterance, then your problem is reduced to an alignment problem--much easier to deal with than a full-fledged speech recognition (plus alignment) problem. You already know what language it is, and you know what consonants and vowels to look out for and the order in which they occur, so you just need to figure out how to align them.

Check out the UPenn Forced Aligner:

https://www.ling.upenn.edu/phonetics/p2fa/readme.txt

They also have a modified web-interface version:

http://fave.ling.upenn.edu/usingFAAValign.html

It's not 100% accurate--it needs human correction here and there--but it might at least save you some time.